# Reading a value from a List<Employee> in Jint

Tags: c#, .net, jint

A general question first: Is there somewhere a documentation about jint? I was not able to find anything apart from the examples on the [github](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) page.

I'm trying to do something like the sample below in Jint. However I'm having troubles to read the value back.

```
var emp = new Employee {Name = "Mike"};

var employees = new List<Employee>();
employees.Add(emp);

var engine = new Engine();
engine.SetValue("employees", e);

// how to get the value "Mike" out of the engine?
JsValue name = engine.GetValue("e[0].Name");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you are trying to do but based on jint's capabilities.
you can use your employees list in JavaScript.

```
        var emp = new Employee { Name = "Mike" };

        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(emp);

        var engine = new Engine();
        engine.SetValue("employees", employees);

        // how to get the value "Mike" out of the engine?
        JsValue name = engine.Execute("employees[0].Name").GetCompletionValue();
        System.Console.WriteLine(name.ToString());//This should return Mike
```

Hope this helps you.